# Где можно использовать UUID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть функция которая генерирует уникальный идентификатор для пользователя.
В каких типах задач можно применять его?

Answer (score 3):

Когда надо знать id (uuid) заранее, еще до вставки в базу, притом id должен быть уникальный. Это позволяет вставлять, например, детальные записи одновременно с мастер-записями, без необходимости узнавать какой там id вставился...

Использование uuid ведет к дополнительным накладным расходам на индексы - размер увеличивается, в отличие от int, соответственно скорость обработки падает. Разница в скорости в одних случаях допустима, в других может оказаться критична.

Comment: Зачем вставлять в базу UUID ?Мы вель не сможем его сравнивать для идентификации юзера

Comment: почему? какая вам разница что сравнивать int или char(16)? [wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID).

Answer (score 1):

Главная задача UUID - обеспечить уникальность ключей, независимо сгенерированных на разных машинах, не имеющих в момент генерации надежного/быстрого/никакого канала связи между собой.

С этой точки зрения, главное их применение - генерация суррогатных ключей в распределенной системе, чтобы не было конфликтов при синхронизации нод.

Также UUID удобен, если нужно минимизировать утечку коммерческой информации. На основании целочисленных ID, выгруженных при обмене сторонней организации, можно строить предположения о количестве записей в вашей базе, а UUID не имеет такого недостатка.